# Vector.push_back Issue

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, memcpy, push-back

The following question concerns the use of a vector and memcpy. Vector functions being used are, .push_back, .data(), .size().

Information about the msg.

a)

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 8<<20
char* msg = new char[(BUFFERSIZE / 4)];
```

Question: Why doesn't code block b) work?

When I run the code below, using vector.push_back in a for loop, it causes the software I'm working with to stop working. I'm not sending the "msg" nor am I reading it, I'm just creating it.

b)

```
mVertex vertex;
vector<mVertex>mVertices;
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
vertex.posX = 2.0;
vertex.posY = 2.0;
vertex.posZ = 2.0;
vertex.norX = 2.0;
vertex.norY = 2.0;
vertex.norZ = 2.0;
vertex.U = 0.5;
vertex.V = 0.5;
mVertices.push_back(vertex);
}
memcpy(msg,                                     // destination
    mVertices.data(),                           //  content  
    (mVertices.size() * sizeof(mVertex)));      // size
```

[Screenshot of the error message from the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBPUa.png)

By adding +1 to mVertices.size() at the very last row, the software works fine. See the example code below.

c)

```
mVertex vertex;
vector<mVertex>mVertices;
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
vertex.posX = 2.0;
vertex.posY = 2.0;
vertex.posZ = 2.0;
vertex.norX = 2.0;
vertex.norY = 2.0;
vertex.norZ = 2.0;
vertex.U = 0.5;
vertex.V = 0.5;
mVertices.push_back(vertex);
}
memcpy(msg,                                     // destination
    mVertices.data(),                           //  content  
    (mVertices.size()+1 * sizeof(mVertex)));    // size
```

The code also work, if I remove the for loop.

d)

```
mVertex vertex;
vector<mVertex>mVertices;

vertex.posX = 2.0;
vertex.posY = 2.0;
vertex.posZ = 2.0;
vertex.norX = 2.0;
vertex.norY = 2.0;
vertex.norZ = 2.0;
vertex.U = 0.5;
vertex.V = 0.5;
mVertices.push_back(vertex);

memcpy(msg,                                     // destination
    mVertices.data(),                           //  content  
    (mVertices.size() * sizeof(mVertex)));      // size
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: First of all, `mVertices.size()+1 * sizeof(mVertex)` is equivalent to `mVertices.size() + sizeof(mVertex)`. It does not matter you "squeeze" addition together, multiplication comes first.

Comment: Please expose the higher powers of code to me senpai

Comment: The size of `msg` is 256 bytes. The size of `mVertices` is 2240 bytes. You are writing 2240 bytes into 256 bytes. This can produce runtime errors.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a basic macro issue: macros define **text** replacements, not logical or arithmetic expressions.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 8<<20
```

creates a text macro. When you use it in this expression (I've removed the redundant parentheses):

```
char* msg = new char[BUFFERSIZE / 4];
```

the preprocessor **replaces** `BUFFERSIZE` with `8 << 20`, so it's as if you had written

```
char* msg = new char[8 << 20 / 4];
```

and the problem is that `8 << 20 / 4` is 256. That's because the expression is evaluated as `8 << (20/4)`, where presumably you intended it to be `(8 << 20) / 4`. To fix that (and you should **always** do this with macros), put parentheses around the expression in the macro itself:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE (8<<20)
```

Incidentally, that's why using a named variable (whether `constexpr` or otherwise) makes the problem go away: the variable gets the **value** `8 << 20`, not the text, so all is good.

Comment: Very well explained answer. This was exactly the problem. Now my code is running smoothly again :)

Answer (score 0):

The define doesn't do what you think.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 8<<20
```

yields `BUFFERSIZE / 4 == 8 << 20 / 4 == 8 << 5 == 256`. So the allocated memory in `msg` is to small to hold `mVertices` and

```
memcpy(msg, mVertices.data(), (mVertices.size() * sizeof(mVertex)));
```

writes into wrong memory. This can produce runtime errors.

You should use `constexpr` instead of `define` to avoid such problems.

Comment: How does that yield 820 ?

Comment: How many bytes are 8<<20?
2^20 = 1,048,576 bits
8 * 1,048,576 bits = 8,388,608 bits
1 bit is 0.125 bytes.
8,388,608 bits * 0.125 = 1,048,576 bytes
Buffersize = 1,048,576 bytes = ish 1048 MB

Comment: @Jesper Size of your buffer is 8<<20 / 4 = 8<<5 = 256. Add parenthesis for correct value: (8<<20) / 4